# Entity Framework Core error in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

When I add ENtity Framework Core 1.1 in a web application with Web API 2, I get the following error during compilation:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1703  Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported: 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication8\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate
>   references.   WebApplication8 C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\CSC 1   Active

Is there any way to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are you working with asp.net core? It seems like you have duplicated packages

Comment: No, I am working on asp.net mvc 5 and web api 2

Comment: As I know ef core only works on .net core, not classic .net